# Android Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <br><table of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: java, php, android, json

I am trying to display information depending on the item pressed in a ListView. When click the item in List view,it will display the subject information.

But i faced a problem that is when click the item in List view,it cannot display the subject information based on the item that i clicked and display error in logcat.

Logcat Json response show that success get the subject information Single Product Details but still failed display subject information.Thanks

```
05-14 17:54:36.671: D/All Products:(1227): {"success":1,"products":[{"session":"2-2014\/2015","subject_code":"BITS 3323 Local Area Network","section":"1\/1","class_ID":"1"},{"session":"2-2014\/2015","subject_code":"BITS 3323 Local Area Network","section":"1\/2","class_ID":"2"},{"session":"2-2014\/2015","subject_code":"BITS 3323","section":"1\/2","class_ID":"8"},{"session":"2-2014\/2015","subject_code":"BITS2323 Wide Area Network","section":"1\/1","class_ID":"9"}]}
05-14 17:54:37.731: E/JSON Parser(1227): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
05-14 17:54:37.731: D/Single Product Details(1227): {"success":1,"products":[{"session":"2-2014\/2015","subject_code":"BITS 3323 Local Area Network","section":"1\/1","class_ID":"1"},{"session":"2-2014\/2015","subject_code":"BITS 3323 Local Area Network","section":"1\/2","class_ID":"2"},{"session":"2-2014\/2015","subject_code":"BITS 3323","section":"1\/2","class_ID":"8"},{"session":"2-2014\/2015","subject_code":"BITS2323 Wide Area Network","section":"1\/1","class_ID":"9"}]}
05-14 17:54:37.731: D/JSON Parser(1227): {"success":1,"products":[{"session":"2-2014\/2015","subject_code":"BITS 3323 Local Area Network","section":"1\/1","class_ID":"1"},{"session":"2-2014\/2015","subject_code":"BITS 3323 Local Area Network","section":"1\/2","class_ID":"2"},{"session":"2-2014\/2015","subject_code":"BITS 3323","section":"1\/2","class_ID":"8"},{"session":"2-2014\/2015","subject_code":"BITS2323 Wide Area Network","section":"1\/1","class_ID":"9"}]}
 05-14 17:54:37.731: W/System.err(1227): org.json.JSONException: No value for product
```

I trying use some suggestion such as change echo->print in php, using require_once 'DB_Connect.php  that provided in previous post to solve `Error parsing data org.json.JSONExceptio` but still does not work

Listview java to passes EditProductActivity2

```
public class AllAttendanceActivity extends ListActivity {

// Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

// Creating JSON Parser object
JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productsList;

// url to get all products list
private static String url_all_products = "http://192.168.1.14/android/get_class.php";

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_PRODUCTS = "products";
private static final String TAG_PID = "class_ID";
private static final String TAG_NAME = "subject_code";
private static final String TAG_SECTION = "section";

// products JSONArray
JSONArray products = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.all_attendance);

    // Hashmap for ListView
    productsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    // Loading products in Background Thread
    new LoadAllProducts().execute();

    // Get listview
    ListView lv = getListView();

    // on seleting single product
    // launching Edit Product Screen
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // getting values from selected ListItem
            String class_ID = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.pid)).getText()
                    .toString();

            // Starting new intent
            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    EditProductActivity2.class);
            // sending pid to next activity
            in.putExtra(TAG_PID, class_ID);

            // starting new activity and expecting some response back
            startActivityForResult(in, 100);
        }
    });

}

// Response from Edit Product Activity
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    // if result code 100
    if (resultCode == 100) {
        // if result code 100 is received 
        // means user edited/deleted product
        // reload this screen again
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        finish();
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}

/**
 * Background Async Task to Load all product by making HTTP Request
 * */
class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(AllAttendanceActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading Subject.. Please wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * getting All products from url
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        // getting JSON string from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_products, "GET", params);

        // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
        Log.d("All Products: ", json.toString());

        try {
            // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                // products found
                // Getting Array of Products
                products = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCTS);

                // looping through All Products
                for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    String class_ID = c.getString(TAG_PID);
                    String subject_code = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                    String section = c.getString(TAG_SECTION);

                    // creating new HashMap
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    map.put(TAG_PID,class_ID);
                    map.put(TAG_NAME, subject_code);
                    map.put(TAG_SECTION, section);

                    // adding HashList to ArrayList
                    productsList.add(map);
                }
            } else {
                // no products found
                // Launch Add New product Activity
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        NewProductActivity.class);
                // Closing all previous activities
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
        pDialog.dismiss();
        // updating UI from Background Thread
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                /**
                 * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                 * */
                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                        AllAttendanceActivity.this, productsList,
                        R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_PID,
                                TAG_NAME,TAG_SECTION},
                        new int[] { R.id.pid, R.id.name,R.id.section});
                // updating listview
                setListAdapter(adapter);
            }
        });

    }

}
}
```

public class EditProductActivity2
     public class EditProductActivity2 extends Activity {

```
EditText txtName;
EditText txtPrice;
EditText txtDesc;
EditText txtCreatedAt;
Button btnSave;
Button btnDelete;

String class_ID;
String subject_code;
String session;
String section;

// Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

// JSON parser class
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();


// single product url
private static final String url_class_detials = "http://192.168.1.14/android/get_class_details.php";

// url to update product
private static final String url_update_product = "http://10.0.2.2/android_connect/update_product.php";

// url to delete product
private static final String url_delete_product = "http://10.0.2.2/android_connect/delete_product.php";

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_PRODUCT = "product";
private static final String TAG_PID = "class_ID";
private static final String TAG_NAME = "subject_code";
private static final String TAG_PRICE = "session";
private static final String TAG_DESCRIPTION = "section";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.edit_product);

    // save button
    btnSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
    btnDelete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDelete);

    // getting product details from intent
    Intent i = getIntent();

    // getting product id (pid) from intent
    class_ID = i.getStringExtra(TAG_PID);

    // Getting complete product details in background thread
    new GetProductDetails().execute();

    // save button click event
    btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // starting background task to update product
            new SaveProductDetails().execute();
        }
    });

    // Delete button click event
    btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // deleting product in background thread
            new DeleteProduct().execute();
        }
    });

}

/**
 * Background Async Task to Get complete product details
 * */
class GetProductDetails extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(EditProductActivity2.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading product details. Please wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * Getting product details in background thread
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        // updating UI from Background Thread
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                // Check for success tag
                int success;
                try {
                    // Building Parameters
                    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pid", class_ID));

                    // getting product details by making HTTP request
                    // Note that product details url will use GET request
                    JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                            url_class_detials, "GET", params);

                    // check your log for json response
                    Log.d("Single Product Details", json.toString());



                    // json success tag
                    success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                    if (success == 1) {
                        // successfully received product details
                        Log.d("JSON Parser",json.toString() );

                        JSONArray productObj = json
                                .getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCT); // JSON Array



                        // get first product object from JSON Array
                        JSONObject product = productObj.getJSONObject(0);

                        // product with this pid found
                        // Edit Text
                        txtName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputName);
                        txtPrice = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputPrice);
                        txtDesc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputDesc);

                        // display product data in EditText
                        txtName.setText(product.getString(TAG_NAME));
                        txtPrice.setText(product.getString(TAG_PRICE));
                        txtDesc.setText(product.getString(TAG_DESCRIPTION));

                    }else{
                        // product with pid not found
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        return null;
    }


    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once got all details
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }
}

/**
 * Background Async Task to  Save product Details
 * */
class SaveProductDetails extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(EditProductActivity2.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Saving product ...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * Saving product
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

        // getting updated data from EditTexts
        subject_code = txtName.getText().toString();
        session = txtPrice.getText().toString();
        section = txtDesc.getText().toString();

        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_PID, class_ID));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_NAME, subject_code ));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_PRICE, session ));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_DESCRIPTION, section  ));

        // sending modified data through http request
        // Notice that update product url accepts POST method
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_update_product,
                "POST", params);

        // check json success tag
        try {
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                // successfully updated
                Intent i = getIntent();
                // send result code 100 to notify about product update
                setResult(100, i);
                finish();
            } else {
                // failed to update product
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }


    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once product uupdated
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }
}

/*****************************************************************
 * Background Async Task to Delete Product
 * */
class DeleteProduct extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(EditProductActivity2.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Deleting Product...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * Deleting product
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

        // Check for success tag
        int success;
        try {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pid", class_ID));

            // getting product details by making HTTP request
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                    url_delete_product, "POST", params);

            // check your log for json response
            Log.d("Delete Product", json.toString());

            // json success tag
            success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
            if (success == 1) {
                // product successfully deleted
                // notify previous activity by sending code 100
                Intent i = getIntent();
                // send result code 100 to notify about product deletion
                setResult(100, i);
                finish();
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once product deleted
        pDialog.dismiss();

    }

}
}
```

PHP CODE

```
$response = array();



require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';
//require_once 'db_connect.php';

// connecting to db
 $db = new DB_CONNECT();

// check for post data
if (isset($_GET["pid"])) {
$pid = $_GET['pid'];

// get a product from products table
$result = mysql_query("SELECT *FROM class WHERE class_ID=$pid ");

if (!empty($result)) {
    // check for empty result
    if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {

        $result = mysql_fetch_array($result);

        $product = array();
         $product["class_ID"] = $row["class_ID"];
         $product["subject_code"] = $row["subject_code"];
         $product["session"] = $row["session"];
         $product["section"] = $row["section"];
        // success
        $response["success"] = 1;

        // user node
        $response["product"] = array();

        array_push($response["product"], $product);

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
        // no product found
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "No product found";

        // echo no users JSON
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
} else {
    // no product found
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "No product found";

    // echo no users JSON
    echo json_encode($response);
}
} else {
// required field is missing
$response["success"] = 0;
$response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

// echoing JSON response
echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

Comment: error in your php code , when the php code is not correct .. you will get an html table that describe the error ..something  like <br><table ..><tr></tr>..</table>

Comment: this means that my php file gt error?
But when in trying this php file it does not show any error

Comment: in  your jsonParser.java add log.i("result",result); //change result to what you have ..maybe it is json .. or i don't know what

Comment: after that post the entire log